# Prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $\langle H \rangle= H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if  $H$ is  a subgroup of $G$ then $\langle H \rangle= H$

**My attempt**: Here $\langle H\rangle$ is the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $H \implies  H \subseteq \langle H\rangle$

$H \subseteq \langle H\rangle \implies $
every element in $H$  would be an element  of $\langle H \rangle $.

Similarly, every element in $\langle H \rangle$ would be an element  of $H$

Therefore $\langle H \rangle= H$.

Is it true?

Comment: The first part looks good to me, you use the definition of $\langle H \rangle$ to conclude that $H \subseteq \langle H \rangle$. However, I would say that showing $\langle H \rangle \subseteq H$ requires a bit more than saying it works "similarly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm convinced by your proof of the first assertion, "every element in $H$ would be an element of $\langle H \rangle$".

But your proof of the second assertion "every element in $\langle H \rangle$ would be an element of $H$", which consists solely of the word "similarly", is quite unconvincing. Given $g \in G$, you have to prove that if $g$ is an element of every subgroup that contains $H$, then $g \in H$. How do you do that? (Hint: prove the contrapositive).

Answer (score 1):

Another way of defining $\langle H\rangle$ is this: the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $H$. (Why?) But now $H=\langle H\rangle$, since, first of all, $H\subseteq \langle H\rangle$, and if $x\in\langle H\rangle\setminus H$, then $x$ is not generated by any of the elements of $H$ (by closure of $H$), and so $\langle H\rangle \subset \langle H\cup\{ x\}\rangle$, a contradiction.